# How to select custom element childrens after attached to dom?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I want to get `transaction-name__inputbox` value when the `transaction-add__button` is clicked. The `transactionAddHandler` is invoked when the button is clicked.

When I try to get that element using `document.querySelector()`, I got null. I can't find how can I get that input box value.

```
const template = document.createElement("template");
template.innerHTML = `
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/transactionAddPanel.css">
  
  <div id="transaction-add-panel">
    <div id="transaction-name">
      <label for="transaction-name">Transaction Name</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Required more then 4 characters" id="transaction-name__inputbox">
    </div>
    <div id="transaction-price">
      <label for="transaction-price">Transaction Price</label>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Rs.10" id="transaction-price__inputbox">
    </div>
    <div id="transaction-add">
      <button id="transaction-add__button">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
`;

export default class TransactionAddPanel extends HTMLElement {
  private readonly transactionAddButton: HTMLButtonElement;

  constructor() {
      super();
      let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
      
      shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
      this.transactionAddButton = <HTMLButtonElement>shadowRoot.querySelector("#transaction-add__button");
  }; 
  
  connectedCallback() {   this.transactionAddButton.addEventListener("click", this.transactionAddHandler)
};
  disconnectedCallback() {
    this.transactionAddButton.removeEventListener("click", () => {
      return
    });
  };
  
  transactionAddHandler() {
    console.log("clicked")
    
 console.log(document.querySelector("#transaction-name__inputbox"))
    // here i got null
  };
};

customElements.define("transaction-add-panel", TransactionAddPanel);
```

Comment: `document.querySelector("#transaction-name__inputbox")` returns null because the element was nowhere to be found in the document. Have you try search it on `Elements` tab in developer console?

Comment: Basically i am doing on my android. I will not able to use developer tool

Comment: Is there any way ? Iam stuck

Comment: obviously, you must be able to inspect your output. otherwise, you may not actually know what happen.

Comment: I suspect `shadowRoot.appendChild` does not append `template` to the `document.body`. Perhaps `shadowRoot` doesnt event exist in `document.body`. `createElement` does not attach an element, it just create it in virtual DOM

Answer (score 0):

An element must be present in a `document.body` for `document.querySelector` to return an `[HTML Element]`. In your case it is not.

I suspect `shadowRoot.appendChild` does not append `template` to the `document.body`. Perhaps `shadowRoot` doesn't event exist in `document.body`. `createElement` does not attach an element, it creates it in virtual DOM.

As a demo I have setup this snippet. It works well if `template` does get appended to `document.body`.

```js
const template = document.createElement("template");
template.innerHTML = `
  <div id="transaction-add-panel">
    <div id="transaction-name">
      <label for="transaction-name">Transaction Name</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Required more then 4 characters" id="transaction-name__inputbox">
    </div>
    <div id="transaction-price">
      <label for="transaction-price">Transaction Price</label>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Rs.10" id="transaction-price__inputbox">
    </div>
    <div id="transaction-add">
      <button id="transaction-add__button">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
`;

// [1]: make sure you got template appended to document.body
document.body.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
document.querySelector("#transaction-add__button").
addEventListener("click",function transactionAddHandler(){
  console.log("clicked")

  console.log(document.querySelector("#transaction-name__inputbox"))
  // here i got [HTML Element]
})
```

Comment: But what to do with shadowDom? I mean custom elements. Is there any approach?